# Website getting zoomed out when using pinch-to-zoom in IOS

Tags: html, css

My website when viewing in iphone gets zoomed out when using pinch-to-zoom and double tapping.
I'm giving a illustration to better understand the problem.
[not the actual website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShSDV.png)

I have added this code to prevent zooming out in mobile device.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

But since IOS no longer support the usage of "user-scalable=no", this code only works on android device.

Further, I have added this code in CSS.

```
body {
   touch-action:pan-y;
}
```

This will prevent the panning in horizontal direction, but still the pinch-to-zoom and double tap zoom works on IOS.

Any ideas on what causing the problem and how to solve it?

It would be preferrable if you guys can tell me any other way to disable zomming in mobile.